# How to edit my openedx home page?

Tags: openedx

The Home page presents a default text :

> Welcome to the Open edX® platform! It works! This is the default
>   homepage for this Open edX instance.

[image]

**Where to go to edit this content ?**

Comment: Given the systematic downvotes on this #openedx tag... thanks to explain your downvotes briefly so I may improve / remove the question if indeed needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer :** found these solutions online but I did not implemented them. I'am summarizing them here for convenience and later testing. ([Source discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/edx-code/1JGJsML8aOQ))

---

There are 2 ways to change you page contents.

### 1. Manually

If you want to manually update the code, edit the main pages are:

- LMS:

  - edx-playform/lms/templates/main.html
- CMS:

  - edx-playform/cms/templates/base.html
  - edx-playform/cms/templates/widgets/header.html

### 2. Via a theme and its edition

1. Get code in : 
   `git clone https://github.com/Stanford-Online/edx-theme /edx/app/edxapp/themes/`
2. Rename scss : 
   `mv _default.scss edx-theme.scss`
3. In `lms.env.json`, set  "USE_CUSTOM_THEME": true " , "THEME_NAME": "edx-theme" in lms.env.json
4. Edit `/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/lms/templates/index.html`